# ssl / https certificate from shady resellers

Tags: ssl, certificate

what do i risk [besides obvious - cc number getting stolen] when buying ssl certificate for https use from one of [many rapidssl resellers](http://www.google.se/search?hl=en&safe=off&num=100&q=rapidssl+certificate+cheap&btnG=Search) rather then directly from [rapidssl](http://www.rapidssl.com/index_ssl.htm) ? disproportion in prices seem quite high: 10$ vs 79$ per year.

where's the catch?  do you have any experience with any of resellers? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's signed by the same root, it comes down to the price and the infrastructure for purchasing (can you do it all online with a credit card, is it easy, etc).

You have to watch out for chained root certificates, where (someone like) RapidSSL signs a certificate, and that company then uses that certificate to sign yours.  Unless you have a good reason, stay away from them.

I've bought certificates from [Namecheap.com](http://www.namecheap.com/) before - they will give you a single root certificate.  See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/4834/good-low-cost-ssl-certificate-providers) for more.

Comment: namecheap showed up as well in my search results and i was considering getting cert from that. so you're saying there ware no problem with them. right?

Comment: None whatsoever - we bought something like 20 certificates for our customers at my last job.

Comment: No problems myself either, though if you already have an account with a registrar for domains it would be worth seeing if they resell certificates too. Unless you'd prefer not to have both domains and certs in the same account, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The risk is low in most cases, though I would recommend going with a company that either you personally have dealt with previously or one that comes with a recommendation from a source you trust.

For instance, most registrars also sell certificates through this sort of reseller agreement, and you'll most likely get the same price or not much more from them.

A short while ago NameCheap were offering a free SSL cert with every new domain registration which is where I got my last couple. You might find that offer still on, or that other registrars are offering something similar.

There is no need to go with a firm you have any reason not to trust, given how many out there resell at more-or-less the same price.

Answer (score 1):

If cost is really the biggest driving factor - why not consider self-signing? It is super easy, and you can add the certificate to the trusted store for your browser - piece of cake for a small business or personal site. Granted, you won't get automatic recognition in a browser - but for cost, you can't beat it:

For Windows/IIS: SelfSSL.exe from the resource kit - 
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/993a8a36-5761-448f-889e-9ae58d072c09.mspx?mfr=true

Apache: Just fire up openssl to generate your certificates.

Comment: -1 - You should never put a self-signed certificate on the Internet.  If you must use a $Free certificate, sign one with a CA you control, so you can add that root to your "trusted roots" list, and revoke it later if you need to.

Comment: Self signed certificates are very worrying to non-understanding users in modern browsers. Try visit a site with a self-signed certificate in either Firefox 3 or IE7 and see what I mean. Self signing is fine for a closed audience, but you would not want to do it for a public site.

Comment: it's mostly curiosity

Comment: David S- luckily most users don't understand certs and will just blindly click through and ignore the cert errors, once they learn the requisite clicks...
;-)