# SSL certificates that works with nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, nginx, ruby-on-rails

All,

After thinking about it, we are planning to buy an SSL certificate. Because an SSL certificate is quite costly, would you be able to share your experience on SSL certificate(s) that works with nginx? I am planning to run Ruby on Rails application. Apache2 will be my last resort.

Thank you for sharing. Really appreciate it.

Comment: what do you mean by "share an SSL certificate with nginx?" Share it with what? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I must have typed to fast. I've fixed the grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL does not have to be costly. See [my question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/82039/difference-between-ssl-products) about why SSL is so expensive, and why they vary so much. Depending on WHY you want the certificate, you can get them from as low as $US10/year (this does away with insurance and fancy dynamic secured logos, etc, but provides the same level of encryption as most of the other certificates). For cheap providers, see [this question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/4834/good-low-cost-ssl-certificate-providers) however don't just read the accepted answer, because there ARE cheaper solutions than GoDaddy.

Now, to certificates that work with nginx, you need to create a CSR, or Certificate Signing Request. This is usually done with OpenSSL. You can [see here](http://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-nginx.htm) for some nginx-specific instructions, but the instructions for any open-ssl will be the same.

As far as setting up the SSL Virtualhosts, [see here](http://rubypond.com/blog/setting-up-nginx-ssl-and-virtual-hosts).

Comment: http://www.startssl.com/ claims to offer free certificates for 1 year. Never tried it though.

Comment: @save, I investigated it. Their browser acceptance is pretty low, and they use a chained certificate. Not ideal really.